# preg_split produces unexpected results

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the PHP `file` command to read in a file as an array. Each line of the array contains numerals such as "  0 0 0 1 22 5 1 71 " etc. There should be 1024 groups of these non whitespace characters and I am trying to extract these into an array

```
// $lines contains each line from file(...)

foreach ($lines as $i => $value) 
{
  $matches = preg_split('/\s*(\d*)\s*/', $lines[$i]);
  echo count($matches);

}
```

However, when I run this, I get a count of 1026, not 1024. What is amiss? When I use

```
 $matches = preg_split('/\s*(\d*)/', $lines[$i]);
```

I get 1027.

Comment: Post the `var_dump` of the `$lines[$i]` in question so it is reproducible and you will more easily get an answer

Comment: You could try `\s*(\d+)\s*` or `\b(\d+)\b` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: The empty matches at the start and end of your string count. But you're using the wrong function anyway. You don't want to `split`, you want to `match`. `preg_match_all("/\d+/", $input, $matches); var_dump($matches[0]);`

Comment: Thanks - I'd forgotten all about this function ( plus I think my regex was a little ropey to begin with). Works a treat now!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions at all. Using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) will likely be faster. And to modify the array in place, just pass by reference to `foreach` (but do [read the warnings](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) pertaining to that practice and use `unset` afterwards.)

```
$lines = file("input.txt");
foreach ($lines as &$value) {
    $value = explode(" ", trim($value));
}
unset $value;
```

Comment: I tried, but the first character in the array is preceeded by three spaces (this doesn't show up above in my preamble), and I needed to be able to strip out these three as well as single spaces. I did a search and found something called "mulitpleexplode" where you can specify more than one delimeter in an array but this didn't work.

Comment: You could just `trim` the value first.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression needs to match the delimiter strings you're splitting on. Your code is likely going wrong because it's trying to include digits in the delimiter. not to mention that `/\s*\d*\s*/` could match virtually *any* combination of whitespace character and digits.

```
$input = '   0 0 0 1 22 5 1 71 ';
var_dump(preg_split('/\s+/', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "22"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [7]=>
  string(2) "71"
}
```